# Onclick leads function leads to increment resets the page, value + 1

Tags: php, javascript, function, session, onclick

I was searching for hours now and still couldn't find the correct answer. This might seem simple but I need your help, here's the
Problem: There are two buttons, 1.) increment button and 2.) decrement(subtract) button, when I click button 1, the value $a get +1 when I click button 2, $a get -1.

Seems simple right?

It should go back to the same page (reload), with the changed value $a

ex:
$a = 0;
   1.) click increment button
   2.) reload page
$a = 1;
   3.) click decrement button
$a=0

very simple, I'm just not that good to figure it out on my own.

Comment: Are you using parseInt before increment?

Comment: So, you want the value of $a to carry over on a refresh?

Answer (score 0):

I am not a php developer but from your question I understand that you lose the value of the variable because it reloads and that resets all variables to their default value. What you sure do is to persist ( could be in cookies, session, or in the server and always load the value from these stores).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to save a variable to be used after reload / page changed you need to store that variable on a cookie or a session. I'll recommend the session in this case. So here you have an example of this:

**Script name:** index.php

```
<?PHP
    /* You need to start a session in order to 
    *  store an retrieve variables. 
    */
    session_start();
    if(!isset($_SESSION['value'])) { // If no session var exists, we create it.
        $_SESSION['value'] = 0; // In this case, the session value start on 0.
    }

    if(isset($_GET['action'])) {
        switch($_GET['action']) {
            case 'add': // Yeah, PHP allows Strings on switchs.
                $_SESSION['value'] ++;
            break;
            case 'remove':
                $_SESSION['value'] --;
            break;
        }
        /* If you avoid the next two lines, you'll be adding or removing when
        *  you refresh, so we'll redirect the user to this same page.
        *  You should change the 'index.php' for the name of your php file.
        */
        header("Location: index.php");
        exit();
    }
?>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>:: Storing user values in session ::</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>The current value is: <?PHP echo $_SESSION['value']; ?></p>
        <p><a href="?action=add" target="_SELF">Increase value</a></p>
        <p><a href="?action=remove" target="_SELF">Decrease value</a></p>
    </body>
</html>
```

If you save that code in a single php file called "index.php" you'll see the behavior you're looking for.

I hope this will be helpful to you and have a VERY HAPPY NEW YEAR!

PS: Note that in this case I've used just single  for the actions. I'm not using Javascript in here because the title of your question says PHP. If you wanna do this using Javascript or JQuery, let me know.